# how to generate instruction for llvm vector comparison

Tags: vector, comparison, llvm

In LLVM, we can create a comparison instruction for scalar instruction easily. For example, if we have:

```
%a = fsub double %1, %2
%b = fadd double %3, %4
%c = fcmp one double %a, %b
```

where instruction %c can be generated by:
c = new FCmpInst(insertAt, FCmpInst::FCMP_ONE, %a, %b, instName)

Can we do the similar comparison conveniently for vector instructions? For example, if %a and %b are the following respectively:

```
%a = fsub <2 x double>, %5, %6;      %5 and %6 are in vector type
%b = fadd <2 x double>, %7, %8
```

Can we have the similar comparison as the scalar version to check the equivalence for %a and %b?

I actually tried the same instruction as the above, but it produces the following error "**void llvm::BranchInst::AssertOK(): Assertion `getCondition()->getType()->isIntegerTy(1) && "May only branch on boolean predicates!"' failed**." when I load the pass.

Answer (score 0):

`fcmp` of a vector returns a vector of boolean results. You'll need to change the way you reduce that into a boolean predicate for branching purposes.

For your case, you'll want to compare the result of the `fcmp` with zero.

Comment: Thanks, Ohmantics. I figured this out. However there is still another problem. I would like to use the return value (the vector) as a condition for a branch instruction. For example, after the compare %c = fcmp one double %a, %b, I want to create an branch instruction, BranchInst::create(BB1, BB2, c, inst). This will not be working because the condition value is a vector not a integer. Therefore, I need to create an instruction similar to X86 intrinsics _mm_movemask_pd(c). Any idea, how can I implement this in IR? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2012-September/053046.html may contain the answer to your question.
It can be summarized to

1. sign extend your boolean vector to an integer vector
2. bitcast the integer vector to a integer of same size
3. make the comparison on the integer

   ```
   %a = fsub <2 x double>, %5, %6;     
   %b = fadd <2 x double>, %7, %8
   %c = fcmp one <2 x i1>, %a, %b
   %d = sext <2 x i1> %c to <2 x i64>
   %e = bitcast <2 x i64> %d to i128
   %f = icmp ne %e, 0
   br i1 %f, label %true1, label %false2
   ```

The sign extension is used so that backends of standard vector instruction sets map this instruction without switching vector size.